# Deleting rows within Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a new programmer to VBA. I am using a simple line to delete rows out of a for-loop I've made. This simple line deletes the current row.

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

I however have content in column D that I don't want deleted. Is there a way to justify "EntireRow" to something else like "A,B,C"?

```
   a  b  c  d
1  x  x  x  N
2  x  x  x  N
3  x  x  x  N
```

X = don't need. N = needed.

Comment: `Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you Record Macro, you get something like:

```
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

so here are few options:

```
Rows(i).Resize(, 3).Delete xlUp

Range("A:C").Rows(i).Delete xlUp

Range("A1:C1").Offset(i - 1).Delete xlUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this VBA code:

```
Sub Delete_Row_If_Not_Whatever()
Dim RowToTest As Long
'Macro deletes entire row if "Whatever" is not found in column "D"

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off screen updating. Code runs faster without screen flicker

'Column Count 4 = "D"
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

'Look for "Whatever" save row and delete other rows. Replace "Whatever" with what you want to keep.
'Column Count 4 = "D"
With Cells(RowToTest, 4)
    If .Value <> "Whatever" _
    Then _
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Next RowToTest

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn on screen updating
End Sub
```

Be sure to save a backup before you begin. :)